# I can't return the height and width values of the image in the for loop and I can't set the color in the masking

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, numpy-ndarray

My first problem is that I want to go around pixel by pixel in the image I cut and count the color values, but I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'width'

My second problem is that when the match_masking_color value is 255, for example, that region becomes blue and even if I set the threshold and convert it into a binary image, it remains blue. For example, I entered the value 255,255,255, but this time the inside of the mouth is red. I want the mouth to be black, the face is white and I can count the amount of these two colors. Here are the results I'm talking about:
[blue mask1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u676X.png)[blue mask2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckiKt.png)[red mouth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgAO1.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("saskin.jpg")

black_count = 0
white_count = 0


def region_of_interest(image, vertices):
    mask = np.zeros_like(img)
    match_mask_color = 255,255,255
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, vertices, match_mask_color)
    masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
    return masked_image

while True:
    # ret, frame = cap.read()
    # frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)

    # print(frame. Shape)    # 480,640
    
    ycrbc = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
    
    minYCrCb = np.array([0,140,90],np.uint8)
    maxYCrCb = np.array([230,170,120],np.uint8)
    imgeYCrCb = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
    skinRegionYCrCb = cv2.inRange(imgeYCrCb,minYCrCb,maxYCrCb)
    skinYCrCb = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = skinRegionYCrCb)
    median_ycrcb = cv2.medianBlur(skinYCrCb, 3)
    
    _, esik = cv2.threshold(median_ycrcb, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    median_binary = cv2.medianBlur(esik, 7)
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(median_binary, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
    max_index = np.argmax(areas)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[max_index])
    
    height, width = h, w
    region_of_interest_vertices = [(width/4, 11*height/12), (width/4, 13*height/16), (3*width/4, 13*height/16), (3*width/4, 11*height/12)]
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cropped_image = region_of_interest(gray_image, np.array([region_of_interest_vertices], np.int32))
    
    _, agiz = cv2.threshold(cropped_image, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    for x in range(agiz.width):
        for y in range(agiz.height):
            pixel = img.getpixel((x, y))
            
            if pixel == (0):
                black_count += 1
                
            elif pixel == (255):
                white_count += 1

    cv2.imshow("ycrbc",ycrbc)
    cv2.imshow("skinYCrCb",median_ycrcb)
    cv2.imshow("binary goruntu", esik)
    cv2.imshow("median_binary", median_binary)
    cv2.imshow("Kesilmiş Görüntü",cropped_image)
    cv2.imshow("agiz", agiz)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
    
# cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How can I make the output consist of black and white colors as I want as a result of this mask? How can I also navigate within the pixel values of the cropped image?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing up two different packages, cv2 and PIL. `width`, `height` and `getpixel` are belonging to Image.Image instances of PIL, while you are using cv2, where images are represented as numpy arrays.
Thus you need to access the image's dimensions by `agiz.shape`:

```
width = agiz.shape[1] 
height = agiz.shape[0]

# accessing a within your for loop
pixel = agiz[y, x]
```

About your error message: It would be more helpful in the future to post the full traceback of the error message, because it directly states where the error occurred.